# How to checkout (on a forked repo) a Pull Request coming from the main repo?

Tags: github, pull-request, git-checkout

Supposedly I find project A really cool and I fork it on my profile. Then I have the forked version of project A; let's name it project B.

A user opens a pull request on project A.
However, since I already have project B (which is the fork of project A), I would like to checkout the pull request that was opened on project A, on my project B.

That would come more handy, considering that project A differs **now** from project B.

Is there any solution on that?
Whatever I found around the net till now is only about checking out a pull request opened on project A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @cpanato mentioned is indeed correct, but only the first step , because the question is about being able to checkout a pull request and not a branch.

The following line needs to be added to your .git/config file (upstream section):

```
fetch = +refs/pull/*/head:refs/remotes/origin/pr/*
```

Then you are ready to fetch the upstream: `git fetch upstream` 
And then you can checkout a specific pull request like below:

```
git checkout origin/pr/11
```

For more details, you can always consult a [short article that I've written](https://toubou91.github.io/checkout-on-a-forked-repo-a-pr-coming-from-the-main-repo/).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set the project A in your remote and the fetch that and then check out the branch that the user open the PR

let's say your `git remote -v` is:

```
origin https://github.com/toubou/projectA.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/toubou/projectA.git (push)
```

you will need to add another entry to map the original project A

```
$ git remote add upstream https://github.com/ORGINALREPO/projectA.git
```

then your `git remote` will be like:

```
origin https://github.com/toubou/projectA.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/toubou/projectA.git (push)
upstream https://github.com/ORGINALREPO/projectA.git (fetch)
upstream https://github.com/ORGINALREPO/projectA.git (push)
```

Now you do:

```
$ git fetch upstream
```

and then check out the branch the user open the pr:

```
$ git checkout branch_name
```